# Remove link(s) from an Activity View screen via crmReplace

Tags: smarty, templates, custom-templates

How should  `{$form.source_contact_id.html}` from \civicrm\templates\CRM\Activity\Form\Activity.tpl be altered so only text remains/ without an URL? [smarty escape](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl) doesn't seems to be a good idea, neither crmReplace (which can replace link attributes like class or href, but doesn't seems to be able to remove link entirely). Any advice, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
{$form.source_contact_id.html|strip_tags:"<a>"}
```

You'll have to add some conditional statements so the smarty only runs when your are viewing the Activity, if you don't the Contact Reference field in edit/create mode **will break**.

Comment: Brilliant Andrei, thank you! Didn't realize Smarty can strip tags selectively. AS for conditional statement(s): there are a plenty of **$actions eq 1/2/3/4..** inside templates, so it looks easy and logical, apart from the fact I can't find a full list of $actions, so, for example, 4 in $actions stands for VIEW, but    8 stands for VIEW too; there are also mysterious ** $action eq 16384 ** where 16384 is ..? Worrying if you, by any chance, could shed some light on? Thanks anyway for genius Smarty hint!

Comment: **1 = Add, 2 = Edit, 4 = View, 8 = Delete** having a look at `/CRM/Core/Action.php` on line 46: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/1e7702fee94c891c1c1b3ec4d43688991f96b6af/CRM/Core/Action.php#L46 you can see, among the rest of the actions, that 16384 **stands for Copy**